# GLSL glass effect plus depth peeling

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm working on rendering a scene that potentially has multiple intersecting transparent objects. This makes the standard method of sorting and drawing back to front problematic (even sorting triangles wouldn't work if the triangles intersect). So I've implemented depth peeling using a GLSL fragment shader to do the second depth test. It's works great.

Now I want to be able to apply certain effects using shaders. One of the objects in the scene is a syringe, and I would like to apply a glass effect. If I was drawing back to front, this would be easy - just start the shader when I draw the syringe, since everything behind it is already in the frame buffer. However, when using depth peeling this approach won't work.

So my questions are:

1. How to I apply shader effects to a single object in a scene when using depth peeling?
2. How do I combine effect shaders with my depth peeling shader (assuming they need to run at the same time)?

I should note that I'm pretty new at using shaders, so code examples are appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "glass effect?" Optical distortion?

Comment: I was planning on starting with optical distortion, since that would rely on knowing what what was behind the glass and is a good example of several other effects I'd like to implement. Eventually I would also look into applying refraction/reflection, but from what I've seen that requires a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if that's possible without ray tracing. As far as I know, the way to use refraction shaders is to do texture lookups in an environment map. This map can be either precomputed, or it's computed on the fly in a separate rendering pass. For the latter option you would need one separate environment map and one extra pass for each object that uses the shader. I kinda doubt that that's possible if the objects intersect each other. Even if it was, for each of these passes you would also need another couple passes for the depth peeling. Now if you also wanted the depth peeling shader passes to factor in refractions for the surrounding objects, this would quickly get out of hand.

Comment: If the object that the effect is being applied to is guaranteed to not intersect, does that change things?